# CSS/HTML Can't align 3 pictures on the same line

Tags: html, css

I have a trouble making website. I can't make 3 photos align in one line.
[image]

```html
<div>
    <img src="Images/mcdonalds.jpg" width="300px" height="180px">
    </div>
    <div>
    <img src="Images/cilipica.jpg" width="300px" height="180px">
    </div>
    <div>
    <img src="Images/mythay.jpg" width="300px" height="180px" >
    </div>
```

`float: left` is used

Answer (score 1):

`div` is inherently `display:block`

you need to use something like a `span` which has `display:inline-block`

https://jsfiddle.net/7daffjh8/2/

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/umwumr7j/embedded/result/)

Change the `display` property of `div` to `inline-block` instead of `block`

Add the below given to your CSS

```
div{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

add `float:left` on div

```css
div {
  float:left
}
```

```html
<div>
      <img src="Images/mcdonalds.jpg" width="300px" height="180px">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="Images/cilipica.jpg" width="300px" height="180px">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="Images/mythay.jpg" width="300px" height="180px" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would help.

**See the Example on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n57mnw5L/)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title></title>
  <style>
    div.container {
      display:inline-block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x180" height="300" width="180" />
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x180"/ height="300" width="180" />
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x180" height="300" width="180" />
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You had used multiple . After closing of  next tag content always displayed in next line.

```html
<div>
    <img src="Images/mcdonalds.jpg" width="300px" height="180px">
 <img src="Images/cilipica.jpg" width="300px" height="180px">
 <img src="Images/mythay.jpg" width="300px" height="180px" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to make the divs display inline. under CSS

```
div{
display:inline;
}
```

or

```
<div style="display:inline;">
            <img src="Images/mcdonalds.jpg" width="300px" height="180px">
            </div>
            <div style="display:inline;">
            <img src="Images/cilipica.jpg" width="300px" height="180px">
            </div>
            <div style="display:inline;">
            <img src="Images/mythay.jpg" width="300px" height="180px" >
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.minihalf-width{
  width:30%;
  float:left
}
div.minihalf-width img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <section>
            <div class="minihalf-width">
                <img src="latest-work/work-1.png"  alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="minihalf-width">
                <img src="latest-work/work-2.jpg"  alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="minihalf-width">
                <img src="latest-work/work-3.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.